# Python complains `time` is naive, while it's actually aware. Bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone, pytz

Okay, with Python 2.7 let's first create two `time` objects using timezones from pytz (2014.07):

```
from datetime import time
import pytz

t1 = time(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
t2 = time(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('CET'))
```

Carefully check that they're both aware:

```
print(t1.tzinfo, t2.tzinfo)
# (<UTC>, <DstTzInfo 'CET' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

Hence, then we can compare them. Let's do it:

```
t1 == t2
# TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware
```

Why does this happen despite they both are aware?

Looks like that's a special case for Python 2.7 and `time` objects when handling timezones with zero offset:

- Works fine with Python 3.4
- If I replace `'UTC'` with `'EET'` -- works fine
- If I replace `'UTC'` with `'GMT'` -- still fails
- If I replace both `time`s with `datetime`s -- works fine (!)

Comment: @derp, you're absolutely right! Thanks, closing